# Automatic ETL data before loading to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I have CSV files added to a GCS bucket daily or weekly each file name contains (date + specific parameter)

The files contain the schema (id + name) columns and we need to auto load/ingest these files into a bigquery table so that the final table have 4 columns (id,name,date,specific parameter)

We have tried dataflow templates but we couldn't get the date and specific parameter from the file name to the dataflow

And we tried cloud function (we can get the date and specific parameter value from file name) but couldn't add it in columns while ingestion

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have authored an article for this kind of problem using Cloud Workflows. When you want to extract parts of filename, to use as table definition later.

We will create a Cloud Workflow to load data from Google Storage into BigQuery. This linked article is a complete guide on how to work with workflows, connecting any Google Cloud APIs, working with subworkflows, arrays, extracting segments, and calling BigQuery load jobs.

[image]

Let’s assume we have all our source files in Google Storage. Files are organized in buckets, folders, and could be versioned.

**Our workflow definition will have multiple steps.**

(1) We will start by using the GCS API to list files in a bucket, by using a folder as a filter.
(2) For each file then, we will further use parts from the filename to use in BigQuery’s generated table name.
(3) The workflow’s last step will be to load the GCS file into the indicated BigQuery table.

[image]

We are going to use BigQuery query syntax to parse and extract the segments from the URL and return them as a single row result. This way we will have an intermediate lesson on how to query from BigQuery and process the results.

Full article with lots of Code Samples is here: [Using Cloud Workflows to load Cloud Storage files into BigQuery](https://medium.com/p/54228d166a7d)

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know of this feature .. will try it and let you know